# Playing Melody with Tone() without using delay()

Tags: arduino-uno

Is there a method to play a Melody with Tone() without using the delay() function?

```
tone(8, melody[thisNote], noteDuration);
int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration;
**delay(pauseBetweenNotes);**
```

Comment: Yes. The same method as is used in the BlinkWithoutDelay example sketch.

Answer (score 4):

As others have noted, this can be done using the same method as used in the standard 'BlinkWithoutDelay' example sketch, and combining that with a state-machine type approach. In a simple state machine you'd assume you can be in one of two states: outputting a tone, and not outputting a tone.

Applying these ideas to your code snippet above:

```
// BEFORE SETUP
const int tonePin = 8;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = pauseBetweenNotes;
const long interval = noteDuration;
boolean outputTone = false;                // Records current state


// IN LOOP
unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

if (outputTone) {
// We are currently outputting a tone
// Check if it's been long enough and turn off if so
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= noteDuration) {
        previousMillis = currentMillis;
        noTone(tonePin);
        outputTone = false;
    }
} else {
// We are currently in a pause
// Check if it's been long enough and turn on if so
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= pauseBetweenNotes) {
        previousMillis = currentMillis;
        tone(tonePin, melody[thisNote]);
        outputTone = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a bit to kabdulla's great example, to be able to use a MelodyArray

```
// declaring variables
const int tonePin = 10;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long pauseBetweenNotes = 250;   // interval between notes (ms)
const long noteDuration = 400;        // (ms)
boolean outputTone = false;                // Records current state
const int MelodyLength = 2;
const int Melody[MelodyLength] = {880, 698};
int MelodyIndex = 0;
unsigned long currentMillis;



void setup() {
}

void loop() {
  currentMillis = millis();
  PlayMelody();
}

void PlayMelody() {
  if (outputTone) {
    // We are currently outputting a tone
    // Check if it's been long enough and turn off if so
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= noteDuration) {
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
      noTone(tonePin);
      outputTone = false;
    }
  } else {
    // We are currently in a pause
    // Check if it's been long enough and turn on if so
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= pauseBetweenNotes) {
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
      tone(tonePin, Melody[MelodyIndex]);
      outputTone = true;
      //Update to play the next tone, next time
      MelodyIndex = MelodyIndex + 1;
      if (MelodyIndex >= MelodyLength) {
        MelodyIndex = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a minimal modification of the basic Arduino toneMelody example to a non-blocking version

```
#include "pitches.h"

// notes in the melody:
int melody[] = {
  NOTE_C4, NOTE_G3, NOTE_G3, NOTE_A3, NOTE_G3, 0, NOTE_B3, NOTE_C4
};

// note durations: 4 = quarter note, 8 = eighth note, etc.:
int noteDurations[] = {
  4, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
};

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
unsigned long pauseBetweenNotes;
int thisNote;

void setup() {
}

void loop() {

  // iterate over the notes of the melody:
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if (thisNote < 8 && currentMillis - previousMillis >= pauseBetweenNotes) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    // to calculate the note duration, take one second divided by the note type.
    //e.g. quarter note = 1000 / 4, eighth note = 1000/8, etc.
    int noteDuration = 1000 / noteDurations[thisNote];
    tone(8, melody[thisNote], noteDuration);

    // to distinguish the notes, set a minimum time between them.
    // the note's duration + 30% seems to work well:
    pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * 1.30;
    
    thisNote++;
  }
}
```