# Is this example for playing music without delay correct?

Tags: code-optimization, code-review

I've followed the directions from [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/26069/30872), to try and play music without delay. This is my code so far:

```
#include "pitches.h"

int melody[] = {
  NOTE_C4, NOTE_G3, NOTE_G3, NOTE_A3, NOTE_G3, 0, NOTE_B3, NOTE_C4
};

int noteDurations[] = {
  4, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
};

const int tonePin = 4;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
int counter = 0;
int numberOfNotes = sizeof(melody)/sizeof(int);
boolean outputTone = false;

void setup() {
  pinMode(tonePin, OUTPUT); 
  //Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  unsigned long noteDuration = 1000 / noteDurations[counter];
  unsigned long pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * 1.30;


  if (counter < numberOfNotes) {
    if (outputTone && ((currentMillis - previousMillis) >= noteDuration)) {
        previousMillis = currentMillis;
        noTone(tonePin);
        outputTone = false;
        counter++;
    }
    else {
        if ((currentMillis - previousMillis) >= pauseBetweenNotes) {
        previousMillis = currentMillis;
        Serial.println(melody[counter]);

        if (melody[counter] == 0) {
          noTone(tonePin);
        } else {
          tone(tonePin, melody[counter]);
        }

        outputTone = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`pitches.h` can be found [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ToneMelody?action=sourceblock&num=2).

So with this code, the music plays, but slower. The pauses between notes seem longer, and I can't figure out why.

Also, I'm not sure where should I increment my notes counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code, your `pauseBetweenNotes` is *in addition to * the duration of the note. In your previous code, IIRC, it included the duration of the note.

Change it to `0.3` times and I think it will behave as you expect.

Comment: This is the [example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ToneMelody?from=Tutorial.Tone). If I understand correctly, a note is played for the duration of `noteDuration`, and then there is a silence for `pauseBetweenNotes`, and so on, and that, `noteDuration` + `pauseBetweenNotes` is the full duration of one note? But `pauseBetweenNotes` is still a full note duration + 30%? (There is no need for the `noTone` function then right?).

Comment: I've never used this `pitches` library, but it looks like `tone()` returns immediately, and the note carries on playing in the background.  In the linked example, the tone will start playing and the code will continue.  It immediately sleeps for 1.3x the length of the note - so the note will finish and then we'll still have 0.3x the length to sleep.  Does that make sense?  In your code above, we wait for the length of the note, and THEN sleep for 1.3x the length of the note.

Answer (score 0):

There's a variable called "pauseBetweenNotes". Try modifying that and see if the pause between notes becomes smaller.

Regarding your counter question, the way the counter is set up looks fine to me.