# Change delay function to millis function to play music

Tags: arduino-uno, millis

I'd like to write a code by changing the delay function in the music playing code to the millis function, do you know how?

```cpp
#include "pitches.h"

// notes in the melody:
int melody[] = {
  NOTE_C4, NOTE_G3, NOTE_G3, NOTE_A3, NOTE_G3, 0, NOTE_B3, NOTE_C4
};

// note durations: 4 = quarter note, 8 = eighth note, etc.:
int noteDurations[] = {
  4, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
};

void setup() {
  // iterate over the notes of the melody:
  for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < 8; thisNote++) {

    // to calculate the note duration, take one second divided by the note type.
    //e.g. quarter note = 1000 / 4, eighth note = 1000/8, etc.
    int noteDuration = 1000 / noteDurations[thisNote];
    tone(8, melody[thisNote], noteDuration);

    // to distinguish the notes, set a minimum time between them.
    // the note's duration + 30% seems to work well:
    int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * 1.30;
    delay(pauseBetweenNotes);
    // stop the tone playing:
    noTone(8);
  }
}

void loop() {
  // no need to repeat the melody.
}
```

Comment: Have you looked and understood the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example, that comes with the Arduino IDE? Have you tried some of the many tutorials about `millis()`, that are available on the web? If yes, what exactly are your problems in changing the code accordingly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Playing Melody with Tone() without using delay()](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17355/playing-melody-with-tone-without-using-delay)

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the `delay()`? Your `tone()` call delays (blocks while playing) as well...

Comment: @DataFiddler, it is one of the basic examples in IDE, not a code by OP

Comment: I still consider my question "why?" valid. If you use blocking tone() calls, creating the "pizzicato" effect via a small delay() is straightforward. 
The call `noTone(8);`is wrong (=unnecessary) here, BTW.
@chrisl's hint regarding BlinkWithoutDelay is good, if you change to non-blocking tone() creation as well. And if you need other things faster than a tone duration.

Comment: @DataFiddler, yes, there is an answer in the duplicate question