# Tone() function pauses between notes

Tags: audio, sound, delay, wave

I tried to experiment with the `tone()` function that comes with the arduino library.

I played around with the standard code example located here:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/toneMelody

This is the code:

```
#include "pitches.h"

int melody[] =
{
  NOTE_C4, NOTE_G3, NOTE_G3, NOTE_A3, NOTE_G3, 0, NOTE_B3, NOTE_C4
};

int noteDurations[] =
{
  4, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
};

void setup()
{
   for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < 8; thisNote++)
   {
      int noteDuration = 1000 / noteDurations[thisNote];
      tone(8, melody[thisNote], noteDuration);
 
      // to distinguish the notes, set a minimum time between them.
      // the note's duration + 30% seems to work well:
      int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * 1.30;
      delay(pauseBetweenNotes);

      // stop the tone playing:
      noTone(8);

   }
}

void loop()
{
  // no need to repeat the melody.
}
```

However, the problem is that there is always a pause between notes.
In musical terms, this is called `staccato`.
I want to be able to play short melodies where there are no delays between the notes, and one note progresses to the next naturally. By the way, this is called `legato` in music theory.

Now, in this example, the delay between the notes sounds good because this "music piece" is supposed to be played this way. But in every other song that i experimented with, there were always some pauses between notes.

This is what this song sounds like: https://soundcloud.com/nikowow-1/normal

Naturally, my mind went to the `delay(pauseBetweenNotes)` function. So i thought this is what causes the delay between the notes. So i set it up to `0.5`. This is what it sounds like: https://soundcloud.com/nikowow-1/05a

As you can hear, it just speeds up the whole song. The delay between the notes remain, but the whole song is sped up (in a higher tempo, so to speak).

In order to better hear the delay between the notes, please take a listen at the song when i selected a value of `3` - causing a smaller tempo, so that the delay between the notes can be more easily audible: https://soundcloud.com/nikowow-1/3a-1

I want to create some melodies where there are no delays between the notes and i am stuck.

EDIT: If you remove the delay line alltogether, the song is played so quickly that only a click sound is heard.

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/BlinkWithoutDelay

Comment: @VE7JRO Thank you! But sorry but i dont understand. How can this be implemented in the `tone()` function?

Comment: I'm probably messing something. So, I'll just ask: What happens if you remove (or comment out) `delay(pauseBetweenNotes);` altogether?

Comment: @timemage Sorry i ommited this in the question and will edit it. But if you remove the delay, the song is played so quickly that only a feint click is heard.

Comment: I see. They made it non-blocking. That's not really what I expected from ArduinoLand.

Comment: Replace the `delay` with a `millis` timer.

Comment: @VE7JRO, why do you point them to millis()? that is not a solution to what the question asks. btw: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17355/playing-melody-with-tone-without-using-delay/89697#89697

Comment: @Juraj This was it! Thank you so much! If you want, you can make a proper answer, so i can upvote and mark it as the selected answer. Once again, thanks a ton!

Comment: @Juraj because ditching the use of `delay` is the most important lesson an Arduino user can learn.

Comment: @VE7JRO, OP is not there yet

Comment: @Juraj - The blocking `delay` will be the next question :)

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you suggest. I should replace `delay` with a `millis` timer to do the delay work? I thought `millis` only counts time. Does it also perform countdown until a specific time?

Comment: @VE7JRO, that question would be a duplicate of https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17355/playing-melody-with-tone-without-using-delay/89697

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is

```
      // to distinguish the notes, set a minimum time between them.
      // the note's duration + 30% seems to work well:
      int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * 1.30;
      delay(pauseBetweenNotes);
```

so the *1.30 creates the pause.

if you change it to

```
   int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration;
```

there will be no pause between notes.

The tone length is specified with the last parameter of the tone() function (`noteDuration` here).